# Solving an equation of one parameter over a range of values of that parameter

Tags: equation-solving

How can I use `NSolve` the following situation (to rectify a cycloid arc mapping with hashes etc.)?

For a specific value on the right-hand side, I use

```
NSolve[8 Sin[t/4]^2 == 4, t]
```

I want to solve over a range of values on the right-hand side, but

```
NSolve[8 Sin[t/4]^2 == n , t, {n, 1, 8, 1}]
```

doesn't work.

EDIT1:

> ```
> nn=10;
> Table[FindRoot[ X[s] == Xsmax  frac, {s , .5}], {frac, 0, 1, 
> 1/nn}] // TableForm
> ```

The suggestion also works for repeated FindRoot as above.

Comment: `NSolve[{8 Sin[t/4]^2 == 4, 1 <= t <= 8}, t]`

Comment: I like to see 8 solutions, first line entry example..

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, `Table[NSolve[8 Sin[t/4]^2 == n, t], {n, 8}]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding from your question is that you want a solution set for each value of n going from 1 to 8 in steps of 1. If this is the case just use Table:

```
Table[NSolve[8 Sin[t/4]^2 == n, t], {n, 1, 8, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may solve it exactly:

```
Solve[8 Sin[t/4]^2 == #, t] /. C[1] -> 0 & /@ Range@8
```